# Pandas optimization for Pandas column selection

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using Python and have a Pandas DataFrame. This DataFrame (products) is created from a CSV file. The CSV file may contain or not a `country` column. In case it exists, I need to use the value, otherwise I will use a default country value.

I'm trying to reduce those 3 lines with a single pandas operation, any suggestion?

```
CONTEXT_COUNTRY = 'US'    
for _, product in products.iterrows():
    item_query = _GetItemQuery(product[DESCRIPTION])
    # Country of the Product. Help return better results.
    country = CONTEXT_COUNTRY
    if COUNTRY in products.columns:
      country = product[COUNTRY]
```

Comment: So if the `country` column exists in the `CSV` file, you don't have to do anything, but if it doesn't exist, you need to create one? Is this the problem, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Analogous to dictionary.get, Series also have a [get](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.get.html) method.

```
...
for _, product in products.iterrows():
    ...
    country = products.get(COUNTRY, 'default')
    ...
```